# Problem with wrong header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm having a strange problem.

In my code I have

```
\tableofcontents
\input{./path/to/my/other/texfile.tex}
```

My summary is well generated, but the rest of the file, which looks like this:

```
\chapter*{A Chapter of Definitions}

%\singlespacing

\section*{A Section}

Some text.


\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{Name of list}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{First item:} Text.
...
```

appears in my dvi with the header `SUMMARY`, but this file didn't belong to the summary. What's the problem? How can I fix it?

My messy main.tex is in this [link](http://pastebin.com/U8Bttxae) in pastebin.

Comment: You should also mention the class you're using. However the problem is that `\chapter*` doesn't set the headers. Some more information is needed: is this the only unnumbered chapter?

Comment: I'm using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{book}`

I have some chapters unnumbered before, but after, this is the only one. After it I have numbered chapters, the first is my introduction. I added a link to my main file in pastebin, please take a look =).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starred sectioning commands don't set header marks, that's why the previous marks still appear. Depending on class, header layout and used header package, you could use `\markboth` and perhaps also `\markleft` yourself, such as

```
\chapter*{A Chapter of Definitions}
\section*{A Section}
\markboth{A Chapter of Definitions}{A Section}
```

or `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`, if they are defined, such as

```
\chapter*{A Chapter of Definitions}
\chaptermark{A Chapter of Definitions}
\section*{A Section}
\sectionmark{A Section}
```

Without concrete code, this is just general advice.

Comment: Hum this worked well, appeared `A Section` in my dvi of `\chapter*{A Chapter of Definitions}` and this I think it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Stefan, some idea on the question below? How to get rid of "0. A Section" in the header. I just want "A Section"

Comment: You can use the upper example with markboth