# Wrong header text

Tags: fancyhdr

*The close question was [asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33879/problem-with-wrong-header). The question I need is in the comments (asked by LaRiFaRi) but never had the answer.*

**How to change "0.0.Intro" into simple "Intro" in the following MWE?**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler,beton}


\usepackage[paperwidth=145mm, paperheight=215mm,inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}

% Redefine the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Header rule's width
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}


\author{A. Uthor}
\title{What is the Title of This Book?}
\date{today}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm}
\pagestyle{style1}
\maketitle


\thispagestyle{empty}
{This page is intentionally left blank}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm,marginparwidth=20mm}
\pagestyle{style2}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\section*{Intro}\sectionmark{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Intro}}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use `\sectionmark` but `\markright{Intro}` or `\markboth{Intro}{Intro}`. `\sectionmark` usually adds `\thesection` in front of the title given by the argument. Or put the into into the frontmatter and use `\frontmatter\chapter{Intro}…\mainmatter`. BTW: KOMA-Script class `scrbook` provides command `\addchap{…}` and `\addsec{…}`, that would not need additional commands to set the page header or a ToC entry.

Comment: Did you test \markboth in your minimal example above?

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can you please, convert the comment into the answer for me to accept it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Would you like to write an answer? (Sergey: other commenters are generally not notified of comments unless you write an at-sign followed by the username, as I did here.)

Comment: I'm very short in time, so I've added only a very short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `secnumdepth` is greater than zero, `\sectionmark` adds the section number `\thesection` (followed by a period and a space) before its argument to build the running head in the page head. You can use `\markright{INTRO}` to set the running head of odd pages or `\markboth{INTRO}{INTRO}` to set the running heads of odd and even pages without section number.

However, I would recommend not to use `\section*{Intro}` but `\chapter*{Intro}`, because the topmost section level in `book` is chapter not section.

Because you are using `book` you could even use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Chapters in the front matter are not numbered automatically. So you can just use `\chapter{Intro}` and will have the entry into the table of contents and the running head.

If you would switch to the KOMA-Script class `scrbook` you could also use `\addchap` or `\addsec`. They work like `\chapter` and `\section` but without a number.